# Linq nested ID to match to list

Tags: .net, linq

I have a function that I use to retrieve data via the entity framework.

```
    public IEnumerable<Deal> GetCategory(int subcategoryId)
    {
        using (var uow = new ReadUow())
        {
            var r = new ReadRepo<Deal>(uow.Context);

            var deals = r.FindBy()
                .Include("DealSubcategories")
                .Where(d => d.DealSubcategories.Any(s => s.SubcategoryId == subcategoryId));

            return deals.ToList();
        }
    }
```

The .Where clause allows me to filter by a single subcategoryId (courtesy Lee and Jon Skeet), but I'm struggling similarly with comparing it to a list in a different query. So instead of a single subcategoryId, I would compare to a List somehow.

Pretty frustrating so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you had an `IEnumerable<int>` called ids that contained the values you wanted to search for:

```
var deals = r.FindBy()
            .Include("DealSubcategories")
            .Where(d => d.DealSubcategories.Any(s => ids.Contains(s.SubcategoryId)));
```

Comment: Thanks Brian for the prompt response. Checked and works great.